# Installing Ubuntu while dealing with partitions (Windows XP)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows-xp, format

I want to switch over to Ubuntu from XP. I looked at my `C:` drive and noticed that it is divided into 3 sections: my antiquated floppy drive (at least, I think that is correct), the C drive, and an unknown partition of 3GB.

My question is, do I need to remove the partition to free up the 3GB (which is FAT32)? I am not a techie, though I wish I was. Are there any simple instructions to deal with this?

Will Ubuntu just write over the unknown partition, or is that wishful thinking? I was considering installing Ubuntu beside XP, but that might be problematic.

Answer (score 2):

**Please Notice this action will delete all your files and partitions and you will loose windows XP so please make a  backup of your important files before doing this**

You can boot using the ubuntu live installer (either by DVD or USB).
then wait until Ubuntu Live loads up.

Run Gparted, then right click on the partitions and click delete.
repeat this steps for all partitions that is not needed. (in your case I think there will be two partitions: 1- your main C drive and another is the unknown 3GB)

once you have completed this click on apply changes.
wait for a while.
and then install Ubuntu by clicking on the installer on the top left of the screen. (Assuming you want to use 13.10)

if you want to have a dual boot system then the story is different (Slightly different):
you can follow this tutorial for dual booting:
https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/installation